# Insert save \n in database

Tags: csv, insert, mariadb

I make an insert .csv to my mariaDB. Every line end with \n. It looks like that:

```
AA;555

BB;666
```

Insert code:

```
load data local infile 'Dane/listycsv' into table lista fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Problem:
MariaDB save to every varchar the \n mark so i have 555\n etc.
What to do???

Comment: Are you sure it is not `\r`, as in `CRLF` line terminator of Windows?

Comment: Thank you very much!! <3
It was really \r\n at the end :)